# TYPO3 display the subpages of sysFolder directory on menu

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a strange behavior of TYPO3 menu, when one of the page is `sysFolder`, the subpages of this folder don't show in the menu. If I change this type to `not visible in menu`, the subpages still don't show up.

The code of my menu looks like this:

```
[PIDinRootline = 1234]
lib.left-menu = COA
lib.left-menu.1 = HMENU
lib.left-menu.1 {
  entryLevel = 2
  expAll = 1
  1 = TMENU
  1.noBlur = 1
  1 {
          wrap = <nav class="left-menu"><ul>|</ul></nav>
          expAll = 0
          noBlur = 1
          NO {
                  wrapItemAndSub= <li class="inactive first">|</li> |*| <li class="inactive">|</li> |*| <li class="inactive last">|</li>
                  ATagParams = 
          }
          CUR=1
          CUR {
                  wrapItemAndSub= <li class="cur_inactive first">|</li> |*| <li class="cur_inactive">|</li> |*| <li class="cur_inactive last">|</li>
                  ATagParams = 
          }
          CURIFSUB=1
          CURIFSUB {
                  wrapItemAndSub= <li class="cur_active first">|</li> |*| <li class="cur_active">|</li> |*| <li class="cur_active last">|</li>
                  ATagParams = 
          }
          ACT=1
          ACT {
                  wrapItemAndSub= <li class="cur_active first">|</li> |*| <li class="cur_active">|</li> |*| <li class="cur_active last">|</li>
                  ATagParams = 
          }

  }
  2 = TMENU
  2.noBlur = 1
  2 {
          wrap = <ul>|</ul>
          expAll = 0
          NO{
                ATagTitle.field = title
                wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
          }
          CUR=1
          CUR {
                wrapItemAndSub= <li class="cur_active2">|</li>
                ATagParams = 
          }
          CURIFSUB=1
          CURIFSUB {
                wrapItemAndSub= <li class="cur_active2">|</li>
                ATagParams = 
          }
          ACT = 1
          ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active2">|</li>
          }
  }
}
[end]
```

Comment: Is the `expAll = 0` in the TMENU the problem?

Comment: Try `special = directory`

Comment: I try it but without any result... I made another menu only for this folder, and it works